# In Rails console how do I find records that below to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models:

1. Workspace (has many projects)
2. Project (belongs to workspace and has many tasks)
3. Task (belongs to project)

In the Rails console, I can do;

```
w = Workspace.find(1)
w.projects.all
```

This returns all of the projects that belong to workspace with Id = 1.  How do o find all of the tasks that belong to workspace with Id = 1?

I have tried:

```
w.projects.tasks.all
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: You can use `has_many :through` association. Ref: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @GokulM worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `workspace` model use the below association:

```
has_many :tasks, through: :projects
```

Also, I recommend you to check the [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post you need to find the task belongs to a particular project that in turn belongs to a particular workspace.

```
 w.projects.tasks.all
```

The above line won't be working as w.projects would returning collection of ActiveRecord and for association to work you need an object.

Assuming you have written necessary association as mentioned by @Abhilash, below mentioned query would achieve would you need.

```
#1st solution
project_tasks = w.includes(:projects => [:tasks]) #eager-loading both project and tasks
#2nd solution
project_tasks = w.projects.map {|project| project.tasks } # will return all tasks
```

Hope it clears your query!!